# How do I pass a javascript function I've already defined into a jquery call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if I have:

```
function example() {
    alert("example");
}
```

Then why doesn't this work?

```
$("h2").click( example() );
```

Does it have to be defined inline?

Comment: Done.  Apologies for the delay.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, but the parens is making the function execute. Use this:

```
$("h2").click( example );
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to just do `$("h2").click(example);` - example should have no parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

```
function example() {
    alert("example");
}

$("h2").click(example);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
$("h2").click(example);
```

or

```
$("h2").click(function() { example(); });
```